# dropdownlist in gridview row data bound is not executing properly

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist in my gridview. The datas in dropdownlist are "Y" and "N".These two letters. If I select Y then the cell value 6 will be need to become zero. But its not working. Here is my code.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
         DropDownList DropDownList3=(DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList");
         //if (DropDownList3 == null)
             //if (DropDownList3.SelectedValue == "Y")
          if(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "Y")

         {
             e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "0";
         }
         else
         {
             e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "1";
         }
        }
}
```

This is my dropdowlist template field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alt">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: How look like Your `TemplateField` and `ItemTemplate` in `GridView` for that ddl?

Comment: are you trying to change the value of `cell[6]` on dropdown change event or are you trying to make a conditional formatting on `databound`?

Comment: Yes I need to change the value in cell[6]. If I put if (DropDownList3 == null)
then it is working but only problem with if(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "Y")

this command

Comment: your dropdown list's original id is `DropDownList3`. Surely `(DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList")` will return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You have to set `AutoPostBack="true"` for `DropDownList3`, and You have to create EventHandler for ddl, but in `RowCreated` not in `RowDataBound`.

There is example (it's vb.net) :

*aspx:*

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alt">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
     <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and then, code behind :

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grid1.RowCreated
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList3"), DropDownList)
            AddHandler ddl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ddlChange
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub ddlChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = ddl.NamingContainer
        If ddl.SelectedItem.Text = "Y" Then
            row.Cells(6).Text = "0"
        Else
            ' do what You want
        End If
End Sub
```

It's very important You don't bind Your `GridView` after every `PostBack`, and, of course, `EnableViewState` must be set to `True`.

Since I'm working in `vb.net`, I'll try to convert this code into `c#`.

**Update :**

There is `c#` code (I used online converter) :

```
private void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
   if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)) {
     DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList3")));
     ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ddlChange);
   }
}

private void ddlChange(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)(sender));
    GridViewRow row = ddl.NamingContainer;
    if ((ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "Y")) {
       row.Cells[6].Text = "0";
    } else {
       // do what You want
    }
}
```